# Macro "Save to PDF" saves even on cancels

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

As in the title, I have a problem with a macro. I would like to avoid that the macro saves the pdf file even if i press on `Cancel` in the `Save as` dialog box. What did I miss?

Here's the code:

```
Sub PDFActiveSheet()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strPath As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim strFile As String
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set ws = Foglio5

'enter name and select folder for file
' start in current workbook folder
strFile = Replace(Replace(Foglio5.Cells(14, 2) & "_" & (Foglio5.Cells(14, 4) & "_" & (Foglio5.Cells(15, 10))), "", ""), ".", "_") _
            & "_" _
            & Format(Foglio5.Cells(17, 5), "yyyymmdd\") _
            & ".pdf"
strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile

myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

If myFile <> "False" Then
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

    MsgBox "PDF Creato! Si trova nella cartella di questo file."
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Errore nella creazione del PDF"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Change line

```
If myFile <> "False" Then
```

into

```
If myFile Then
```

---

Explanation:

You declared (correctly) `myFile` as `Variant`. And this type will switch the actual type of the variable when necessary. So, after pressing OK, the routine returns a value of type `String` (containing the path) and on pressing cancel a value of type `Boolean` (containing `False`).